# Cell color overriding cell rounded border

Tags: tikz-matrix

In a table, made with Ti*k*z, I tried to make the first row darker than the rest by, I think, a little of brute force. It happens that the borders I want must be rounded and the extreme cells (north west, north east, south east and south west ones) are overring it as this image shows:

[image]

(The lighter cyan is a little hard to see, but yes, still overriding the border)

How to solve this problem? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=6mm,column 1/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!7}}, column 2/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!7}}, row 1/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!45}}] (func) {

     x & y = 2x + 1\\
    -3&-5\\
    -2&-3\\
    -1&-1\\
    0&1\\
    1&3\\
    2&5\\
    3&7\\
};

\draw [rounded corners=5pt,thick] (func-1-1.north west) rectangle (func-8-2.south east);
\draw [thick] (func-1-1.south west) -- (func-1-2.south east);
\draw [thick] (func-1-1.north east) -- (func-8-1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Got something working for you!

Instead of doing the fill via the matrix command, I did it afterwards, using arcs for the corners.

[image: Tikz colored rounded table fixed]

The code requires `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` because relative coordinates are calculated. Also, note how I am using layers to have the fill go behind the text of your matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum height=6mm,column 1/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!7}}, column 2/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!7}}, row 1/.style={nodes={fill=none}}] (func) {
     x & y = 2x + 1\\
    -3&-5\\
    -2&-3\\
    -1&-1\\
    0&1\\
    1&3\\
    2&5\\
    3&7\\
};

% Fill in top row
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \filldraw [fill=cyan!45,thick] (func-1-1.south west) -- ($ (func-1-1.north west)+(0,-5pt)$ )
    arc (180:90:5pt)
    -- ($ (func-1-2.north east) + (-5pt,0) $)
    arc (90:0:5pt)
    -- (func-1-2.south east);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw [rounded corners=5pt,thick] (func-1-1.north west) rectangle (func-8-2.south east);
\draw [thick] (func-1-1.south west) -- (func-1-2.south east);
\draw [thick] (func-1-1.north east) -- (func-8-1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The path starts at the south-west corner of the first row. Then it goes up to the top-left corner, just 5pt below, which is the radius of your rounded corner. Then, I have the arc of 5pt, and you see how the pattern continues all the way to the south-east corner of the first row.

I must admit I'm not very familiar with tikz, so perhaps there is a quicker way to do this. Anyway, I think this is a very versatile technique, and that has some elegancy too!

Finally, I think this table is acquirable using normal TeX. Personally, I would prefer that for use in documents. Ask me if you need assistance on that.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (version ≥ 6.23).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{c|c}[rounded-corners,hvlines,columns-width=20mm,color-inside]
  \rowcolor{cyan!45}
    x  & y = 2x+1 \\
  \Hline
  \Block[fill=cyan!7]{*-1}{} % color for the first column
    -3 & \Block[fill=cyan!7]{*-1}{} % color for the second column
         -5 \\
    -2 & -3 \\
    -1 & -1 \\
    0  & 1  \\
    1  & 3  \\
    2  & 5  \\
    3  & 7  \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]