# How to highlight some cells in confusion matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix

I am trying to draw the following figure:

[image]

I have found an example to create the table in [`confusion matrix using only LaTeX code`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271473/131975) and tried to adapt the solution to my table

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[c][1.7cm][c]{1.7cm}{\centering #1}}%
}
\newcommand\MyVBox[1]{%
  \parbox[c][1.7cm][c]{1cm}{\centering\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\MyHBox[2][\dimexpr1.7cm+2\fboxsep\relax]{%
  \parbox[c][1cm][c]{#1}{\centering\bfseries #2}%
}
\newcommand\MyTBox[4]{%
  \MyVBox{#1}\MyBox{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#3}\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
  \MyBox{#4}\par\vspace{-\fboxrule}
}

\begin{document}

    {
    \offinterlineskip
    % \raisebox{-5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c][0pt][c]{1cm}{\textbf{Source2}\\[20pt]}}}\par
    % \hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox[\dimexpr5.1cm+6\fboxsep\relax]{Source1}\par
    \hspace*{1cm}\MyHBox{LH}\MyHBox{RH}\MyHBox{Other contact}\par
    \MyTBox{Type 0}{25}{0}{0}
    \MyTBox{Type 1}{1}{43}{1}
    \MyTBox{Undetected{0}{5}{-}
    }

\end{document}
```

and it does not compile. It shows, `Missing \endcsname inserted.` error.

I would like to generate the figure above and, if possible, use tikz and standalone documentclass.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610750/197451 -- and -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558899/197451 -- and -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69713/matrix-change-row-or-column-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={anchor=center, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, align=center, draw, text width=1.7cm}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}}] (A)
{
    & LH & RH & {Other contact} & {Other\\ No contact}\\
    Type 0 & 25 & 0 & 0 & 3\\
    Type 1 & 1 & 43 & 1 & 2\\
    Undetected & 0 & 5 & -- & --\\
};
\draw[green!80!black, line width=1mm] (A-2-2.north west) rectangle (A-3-3.south east);
\draw (A-2-2.north west)-- node[above right]{Real} node[below left]{AI model} (A-1-1.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}   
 
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,first-col,first-row,columns-width=auto]
\diagbox{Al model}{Real}
& LH & RH & \Block{}{Other\\ contact} & \Block{}{Other\\ No contact} \\
Type 0     \quad & \Block[draw=green,line-width=1pt,transparent]{2-2}{}
                   25 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
Type 1     \quad & 1  & 43 & 1 & 2 \\
Undetected \quad & 0 & 5 & -- & -- 
\end{NiceTabular}  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]